# Role of Service Registry to build a session factory?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, configuration, sessionfactory

While I am using the following recommended way in Hibernate 4.3 to create Session Factory,

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(CONFIGURATION_LOCATION);  
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

I tried to find how the above code is working by reading Hibernate docs, 
The Configuration object is used to specify configuration properties which we specify in hibernate.cfg.xml.
Session Factory is single for an application(in case application has to connect one database) and used to create sessions.

But I could not understand what this service registry is doing in creation of session factory and why from hibernate 4.3, Standard Service Registry Builder is used? What is the actual use of this class and why it is used to create Session Factory ? Which services are being talked about in Service Registry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ServiceRegistry` allows Hibernate to initialize Services such as:

- JTA transaction coordinator
- Caching service
- JMX provider

The role of the `ServiceRegistry` is to provide a flexible way of bootstrapping Hibernate services. Some applications use a programmatic-style of creating a SessionFactory, while other environments bootstrap services through an external mechanism, like OSGI.

Comment: ..but I can obtain `session.beginTransaction();` even when I don't pass ServiceRegistry in buildSessionFactory..

Comment: The `ServiceRegistry` is used to build a `SessionFactory`. The `SessionFactory` is used to create a `Session`. So, without the `SessionFactory`, you'd not have any `Session` instance.

Comment: My question was different. I know what you wrote and I agree.. but when you build the `SessionFactory`, you can do that without passing in `serviceRegistry` and transactions would still work.

Comment: First of all, you didn't ask any question. You made a statement. Second, the `SessionFactory` is built like this: `BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder` -> `BootstrapServiceRegistry` -> `StandardServiceRegistry` -> `MetadataSources` -> `MetadataBuilder` -> `MetadataImplementor` -> `SessionFactoryBuilder` -> `SessionFactory`. So, since Hibernate 4, the `ServiceRegistry` is always used to build a `SessionFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

Services and Registries are new as a formalized concept starting in 4.0.

Services provide various types of functionality, in a pluggable manner. For, example  Hibernate needs to be able to access JDBC Connections to the database. The way it obtains and releases these Connections is through the ConnectionProvider service.

A ServiceRegistry, at its most basic, hosts and manages Services. Services have a scope, it might depend on other services. And they need to be produced (choose using one implementation over another). The ServiceRegistry fulfills all these needs.In a concise definition, the ServiceRegistry acts as a inversion-of-control (IoC) container, managing Services, their lifecycles and dependencies.

The above points have been referenced from the below link,please visit it for more details,it will be quite helpful in further clearing your concepts

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/registries/ServiceRegistries.html